# Adding a new dependency to a module

Tags: 8, entities, updating

As a module maintainer, I want to add a dependency to one of my existing modules, so that my entity can use a field type plugin declared by the dependency.

What steps do I need to take to make sure that:

1. `entup` doesn't WSOD because my new field depends on a non-existent module.
2. Drupal end-users get prompted to download and install the new dependency.

I did find another similar issue -- [What is the protocol for adding a new module dependency to a module that has only had a dev release?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58234) -- which deals with Drupal 7. This will help address question #2, but doesn't speak to the added complexity of `entup`.

I also found an issue dealing with deployments via drush -- [Enable new modules dependencies on deploy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77533) -- but this doesn't address my questions either.

Any other tips or advice?

Comment: a) use dependency in your module info file, b) implement hook_requirements, c) activate the field only if the other module exists(ie. soft dependency).

Comment: I think the question is asking what can you do _after_ you've enabled the module and now need a dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Ivan Jaros is correct.

a) use dependency in your module info file, b) implement hook_requirements, c) activate the field only if the other module exists(ie. soft dependency).

> @Kevin, *after* you've enabled the module

Use a) and c) above.

> 2. Drupal end-users get prompted to download and install the new dependency.

In c) you need to set a message to the user explaining why the field is unavailable and where to get the dependency.  Use function drupal_set_message.

Links:

D8: module exits, https://www.drupal.org/node/1894902 , see \Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists($module)

D8: set message,  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/8.4.x

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work if you add a dependency whose class is declared in the modules service.yml. I think there is no soft dependency for services.